# Draw lines from file

Tags: java, file, user-interface, graphics, 2d

I need to make GUI app that takes coordinates from file that user selects and make a lines with them using .drawLine. I have tried to saving the points to ArrayList and then initialize them but i dont know how to continue and make it so it works. Please help me.

The file looks like this and can by any type.

- 2,4,3,8  (x1, y1, x2, y2)
- 8,0,7,20
- 0,0,800,962

This is the code that works the most.

```
public class Line extends JPanel {

        ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<>();

        public Line() {
            points.add(20);
            points.add(40);
            points.add(250);
            points.add(40);
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

            for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                g2d.drawLine(points.get(i), points.get(i), points.get(i), points.get(i));
                System.out.println(points.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: so what's the problem now? Instead of adding values to an arraylist manually, you want it to add to the array list from the file?

Comment: Yes, also the code doesnt work the way it should. I need to make line from the coordinates but it makes only 2 dots.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could read the file and store the lines information, then draw them.

It uses the [draw(Shape)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#draw(java.awt.Shape)) method of `Graphics2D` for convenience, so that you can directly store `Shape` objects when reading the file.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Line extends JPanel {

    ArrayList<Shape> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    public Line() {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path_to_your_file"))) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            // split the line on the comma separator    
            String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().trim().split("\\,");

            // read the coordinates
            int x1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
            int y1 = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
            int x2 = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
            int y2 = Integer.valueOf(parts[3]);

            // create a Line and store it
            lines.add(new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2));

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        // draw all the lines
        for (Shape line : lines) {

            g2d.draw(line);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So first read the file, then add to the list.

Also it's only drawing dot's cos of your loop. When it loops if the first number is 8 what your loop draws is `g2d.drawLine(8,8,8,8);`

Here's my code snippet. Not tested but should work fine:

```
ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<>();

public Line(String filePath) {
    points = readFile(filePath);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    if(points!= null && points.size()>=4) {
        g2d.drawLine(points.get(0), points.get(1), points.get(2), points.get(3));
    }
}

public ArrayList<Integer> readFile(String filePath){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

    try {

        //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
        fr = new FileReader(filePath);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = sCurrentLine.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
                try {
                    list.add(Integer.parseInt(splitted[i].trim()));
                }
                catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(splitted[i] + " is not a valid number/integer");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(list);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (fr != null)
                fr.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```